# How to set a property of iTunes ScriptingBridge using Swift protocols

Tags: swift, macos, itunes, scripting-bridge

I want to set the rating of a track in Swift 2.3/3 using the iTunes ScriptingBridge framework. I have the Swift iTunes *header* with the protocol definition as this (full *header* [here](https://gist.github.com/pvieito/3aee709b97602bfc44961df575e2b696)):

```
@objc protocol iTunesTrack: iTunesItem {
    @objc optional var album: NSString {get set}
    @objc optional var albumArtist: NSString {get set}
    @objc optional var rating: Int {get set}
}

extension SBObject: iTunesTrack {}
```

But when I try to set the rating:

```
var iTunesApp = SBApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.iTunes") as! iTunesApplication
var currentTrack = iTunesApp.currentTrack
currentTrack.rating = 10
```

Xcode compiler gives me this error:

```
Cannot assign to property: 'currentTrack' is inmutable
```

How I make it mutable? I know this code works in Objective-C but I cannot make it work in Swift and it doesn't work using the Objective-C header and a Objective-C Bridging Header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the `setRating` method in the **Objective-C** code, I can't use the `rating` property to set the rating.

```
iTunesApplication *iTunes = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.iTunes"];
[[iTunes currentTrack] setRating:60];
```

Same in **Swift** with the `iTunes.h` file.

---

This works on **Swift v2.2**:

- In your "**iTunes.swift**" file, you must add the `setRating` function
- > ```
  > @objc optional var rating: Int {get}    
  > @objc optional func setRating(_: Int)
  > ```

---

- The Swift code:
- > ```
  >    let iTunesApp = SBApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.iTunes")  as! iTunesApplication
  >    let currentTrack = iTunesApp.currentTrack
  >    currentTrack!.setRating!(10)
  > ```

Comment: Oh, perfect. Thank you!